# Struggling with a complicated query on row-based Field/Value table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Bare with me for a little bit of setup here please.

I have a table `MAIN` that has a Field/Value representation that looks like this:

[image]

I have another table called `STORE_FLAG`:

[image]

I am trying to write a parameterized query for which I will be given one FIELD_ID and one or more IDs from the `STORE_FLAG` table.

What I need to do is select from the `MAIN` table ROW_IDs where:

 for the given FIELD_ID, the VALUE = 'YES' AND

 for the given STORE_FLAG_IDS, ANY of those FIELD_IDs correspond to a VALUE = 'x' in the `MAIN` table.

Not that this would be a good idea, but I cannot pivot the whole table into a column-based table to then do a traditional where clause.

### Example:

Given a Field_Id = 1 and a list of StoreIds = (30,50). I would want to return row_ids 1 and 2. This is because row_id 1 and 2 have a field_id 1 with value 'YES' AND at least one of the field_ids 3 and 5 have a value 'x'. But row_id 3 has a value of *null* for both field_id 3 and 5 and row_id 4 has a field_id 1 with value = 'NO'.

I was thinking something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ROW_ID FROM MAIN
WHERE (FIELD_ID = :providedFieldId OR FIELD_ID IN (SELECT FIELD_ID FROM STORE_FLAG WHERE ID IN :providedStoreIdList))
AND (FIELD_VALUE = 'YES' OR FIELD_VALUE = 'x')
```

which (I think) works, but feels naïve to me..? I feel like there is some sort of super duper grouping way to do this, but I can't wrap my head around it. Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: Should ALL of the :providedStoreIdList in the "in" list be present with field_value='x', while pulling out the row_id in the final output.? It would help if you can provide the expected output results

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph in the example section of my post I give an example of expected output with sample input. I am looking for ANY one of the :providedStoreId list be present with field_value = ‘x’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a way to do this

```
select distinct m.row_id
  from main m
 where m.field_id=:providedFieldId
   and m.field_value='YES'
   and exists (select 1
                 from STORE_FLAG sf
                 join main m2
                   on sf.field_id=m2.field_id
                where sf.id in ('30','50') /* you need to bind the values from :providedStoreIdList using a table function*/
                  and m2.field_value='x'
                  and m2.row_id=m.row_id
               ) 

link on how to bind an in list
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:110612348061
```

Comment: Of course! EXISTS is the way. I will try this and mark as answer in a few hours.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was able to adapt it from my simplified example to the real deal and its working great!

Answer (score 0):

Your provided solution /query will not work as you say. Because in your last line of query [AND (FIELD_VALUE = 'YES' OR FIELD_VALUE = 'x')] conflict with your requirement . Using your query, you will get ROW_ID if any one is true either FIELD_VALUE = 'YES' OR FIELD_VALUE = 'x'. Which is wrong. You can see below query-

```
SELECT SUB_QUERY.ROW_ID FROM 
(
select DISTINCT MAIN.ROW_ID,MAIN.FIELD_VALUE from STORE_FLAG
RIGHT OUTER JOIN MAIN ON STORE_FLAG.FIELD_ID=MAIN.FIELD_ID
WHERE ((STORE_FLAG.ID IN ('202','203') AND MAIN.FIELD_VALUE='x') 
OR (MAIN.FIELD_ID ='1' AND MAIN.FIELD_VALUE='YES'))

)  SUB_QUERY
GROUP BY SUB_QUERY.ROW_ID
HAVING (LISTAGG(SUB_QUERY.FIELD_VALUE, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SUB_QUERY.ROW_ID) IN ('YES,x','x,YES'))
```

I think you need to run and understand my sub query part at first.